# Use JQuery-click() on IPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jsf, freeze

that seems tricky. My IPad freezes and it seems that this line of code is responsible for that:

```
jQuery('#form_showAllUserHints').click();
```

The HTML related to the event is here:

```
<input id="form_showAllUserHints" class="hidden" type="button" value="showUserHints" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('form',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){prepareHintMessages();},'similarityGroupingId':'form_showAllUserHints','parameters':{'userPrefActionParamShow':'NEW_PATIENT_HINT','form_showAllUserHints':'form_showAllUserHints'} } );return false;" name="form_showAllUserHints">
```

As you can see JavaServerFaces-generated Ajax-JavaScript-Code should get triggered from a JQuery-click()-Action. How can I handle this on an IPad, I read that IPads do not like click()-JQuery-Action?

There were somewhat similar situations and I tried to go for an IPad-only way like this
(I guess there is no jQuery-touchstart()-function, I just want to show my plan to solve this problem):

```
function clickShowAllUserHintsButton(){
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
if (isiPad) {
    jQuery('#form_showAllUserHints').touchstart();// IPad-Bug: jQuery()-click geht nicht: http://www.mitch-solutions.com/blog/17-ipad-jquery-live-click-events-not-working
} else {
    jQuery('#form_showAllUserHints').click();// IPad-Bug: jQuery()-click geht nicht: http://www.mitch-solutions.com/blog/17-ipad-jquery-live-click-events-not-working
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried jQuery('#form_showAllUserHints').trigger("click"); ?

Comment: jQuery('#form_showAllUserHints').trigger("click"); did not change this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a special reason why you call the `click()` function of the button, but can't you just call the function that you bind to the button's click event directly?

So instead of calling

```
jQuery('#form_showAllUserHints').click();
```

Couldn't you just call

```
A4J.AJAX.Submit('form',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){prepareHintMessages();},'similarityGroupingId':'form_showAllUserHints','parameters':{'userPrefActionParamShow':'NEW_PATIENT_HINT','form_showAllUserHints':'form_showAllUserHints'} } );return false;
```

If you need the click on the button to add the button's value to the form request, you could add the parameter programatically to the form's action URL before calling that function.

Comment: Pragmatic and simple!  I like it!